# Reference a record from within itself during construction

Tags: f#, record

I am trying to create a record which uses one of the previously defined fields to calculate the value of another, within the same constructor. e.g.

```
myRecordType = {Foo:int; Bar:int[]}

myRecord = {Foo = 5;
            Bar = Array.init Foo (fun i -> i)}
```

When I try this it doesn't recognise `Foo` as already existing. I also can't reference `Foo` using `myRecord.Foo`, but that makes sense since `myRecord` hasn't been constructed yet. However I would've thought that `Foo` and `Bar` would be in the same scope, so `Bar` could access `Foo`, but apparently not.

The size of the `Bar` array depends on the value of `Foo`, so how is it possible to set up a record of this format?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31943698/126014

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot reference other fields, you shouldn't even take for granted the order of fields evaluation.

You can do it by additional let binding:

```
let myrecord = 
    let calcedFoo = 5
    { Foo = calcedFoo; Bar = Array.init calcedFoo id }
```

You can think of record construction expression as a function where right sides of assignments are parameters passed to that function.

Comment: ah, I was afraid I might have to do that. The values for each of my record fields are read from a file, in order, so I'll have to have additional lets for everything up to the "Foo" field. Bit verbose but if it's the only way to do it.. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I would go with what @Bartek suggests and use local `let` binding to store all pre-computed values that you need to have before you can create the record.

That said (depending on your domain), you might also be able to change the structure of your record, so that you have one record with all the primary values and another record that contains the primary one and adds all secondary values:

```
type MyRecordPrimary = { Foo:int }  
type MyRecord = { Primary:MyRecordPrimary; Bar:int[] }

let myPrim = { Foo = 5 }
let myRec = { Primary = myPrim; Bar = Array.init myPrim.Foo (fun i -> i)}
```

Doing this just to make the construction a bit shorter would be silly, but if the *primary* record actually represents something in your domain, then this might be a good alternative.